# How to prevent reloading the ng-template when clicking on the panel (ngb-panel) in an accordion (ngb-accordion)

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, typescript, angular9

I have used an "ngb-accordion" and for every ngb-panel I have a separate component and I have loaded it in an ng-template. Every time when I'm opening a panel, the constructor and the ng-init methods of the relevant component are getting triggered. Is there any workaround to trigger these methods only once? I just want to load the accordion form controller values only once.

Comment: Hello. `<ngb-accordion [destroyOnHide]="false">` use this option.

Comment: Please add a demo link or provide the code

Comment: @GaurangDhorda thanks a lot. [destroyOnHide]="false" option is doing the job. thanks again.